# How to enable multiple spellchecker dictionaries in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dictionary

I am new to Mac, and I have my rough time (missing keys, wrong shortcuts and etc). But I don't give up. I am a JS developer and computer user with almost 20 years of Windows and Linux (Debian, Ubuntu) experience. I am also bilingual, my second language is english. In Chrome for Windows or Linux one can add as many dictionaries as pleased. Then it is very comfortable to switch between them by clicking right mouse button in the textarea (take a look at the picture). How to make it in osx?
[image: Picture of spellchecker options]

Answer (score 1):

Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar